# How to find document with a max field value and update it in one go (atomically)?

Tags: mongodb

We can use a line like this to find doc with a max value

```
db.collection.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1)
```

but it is impossible to chain update operation and find -> update means two server call which I'd like to avoid.

Is there another way to find and update item in on operation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this once.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$set": {
    key: 3
  }
},
{
  sort: {
    _id: -1
  },
  upsert: true
})
```